# El RewriteEngine On se debe usar solo una vez en el .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Estoy usando mi archivo **.htaccess** para redirigir de **HTTP a HTTPS** y para **eliminar la extensión .PHP** de mis direcciones URL.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Debo usar el `RewriteEngine On` cada vez que vaya a hacer una nueva "regla"?

*Mi archivo htaccess:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On // ¿Debería quitar esta línea?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Depende de cómo tengas organizado el contenido de tu `.htaccess`. Es lógico que si esas directivas van así seguidas las puedes poner dentro de un solo bloque. Pero no hay ningún problema si abres y cierras varios, [como dice Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine): *Use this directive to disable rules in a particular context, rather than commenting out all the RewriteRule directives.* y también *Note that rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts. This means that you need to have a RewriteEngine on directive for each virtual host...*